# How to manage Session in Restful jersey?

Tags: java, rest, session, caching, openid

In my application I am validating the user locally by matching the password and email id in local database and creating a session key using the JAVA UUID generator and storing it in Guava Cache and checking it with every request come from user.Now I am also validating the user by the  OpenID authentication using the front end now i want to manage session for users those are login using  OpenID
using the same approach.

In back-end i am using the restful jersey service,hibernate,PostgreSQL and front end is HTML5  and may be android client and so on.

Now I am stuck that when user is validating through front end using the OpenID how I maintain the session using above approach ?

Comment: Can you create user in local database for OpenID user?

Comment: @ThangHoang  is it will be better approach or i can use any other option ?

Comment: did you find your solution?

Comment: @ThangHoang Now I am creating the partial profile of users in my local database those are coming via open id only validating there email id in database and creating a session key.

Answer (score 0):

Now I am creating the partial profile of users in my local database those are coming via open id and validating only their email id in database and creating a session key using the JAVA UUID generator and storing it in Guava Cache and checking it with every requests comes from user.